# Query to categorize metrics based on the rules set up

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following tables

**Metric_Threshold**
This table contains the threshold ranges for each metric

```
+----------+--------------------+--------+---------+
| MetricId | Threshold_Category | Symbol | Values1 |
+----------+--------------------+--------+---------+
| Met1     | In SLA             | >      | 80      |
| Met1     | Mature             | >=     | 70      |
| Met1     | Satisfactory       | >=     | 60      |
| Met1     | Needs Improvement  | <      | 60      |
| Met2     | In SLA             | =      | Y       |
| Met2     | Out of SLA         | =      | N       |
| Met3     | Mature             | =      | 0       |
| Met3     | Needs Improvement  | =      | 1       |
| Met4     | In SLA             | >      | 80      |
| Met4     | Mature             | >=     | 70      |
| Met4     | Satisfactory       | <      | 60      |
| Met4     | Needs Improvement  | <      | 50      |
+----------+--------------------+--------+---------+
```

**Metric_Report** This table contains the values reported against the metrics for each month.

```
+----------+----------------+---------------+
| MetricId | reporting_date | report_values |
+----------+----------------+---------------+
| Met1     | 2020-01-01     | 72.15         |
| Met2     | 2020-01-01     | Y             |
| Met3     | 2020-01-01     | 0             |
| Met1     | 2020-02-01     | 80            |
| Met2     | 2020-02-01     | Y             |
| Met3     | 2020-02-01     | 1             |
| Met1     | 2020-03-01     | 60            |
| Met2     | 2020-03-01     | Y             |
| Met3     | 2020-03-01     | 1             |
| Met4     | 2020-03-01     | 50            |
+----------+----------------+---------------+
```

I am trying to get a view/query that would categorize the metric_report values into the corresponding range.

**Expected output**

```
+----------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
| MetricId | reporting_date | report_values |       Range       |
+----------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
| Met1     | 2020-01-01     | 72.15         | Mature            |
| Met2     | 2020-01-01     | Y             | In SLA            |
| Met3     | 2020-01-01     | 0             | Mature            |
| Met1     | 2020-02-01     | 80            | Mature            |
| Met2     | 2020-02-01     | Y             | In SLA            |
| Met3     | 2020-02-01     | 1             | Needs Improvement |
| Met1     | 2020-03-01     | 60            | Needs Improvement |
| Met2     | 2020-03-01     | Y             | In SLA            |
| Met3     | 2020-03-01     | 1             | Mature            |
| Met4     | 2020-03-01     | 50            | Satisfactory      |
+----------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

the difficulty i face is that i cannot hard code the ranges for each Metric since the values are likely to be modified by the user

I can accomplish using a dynamic sql to construct the query, followed by pushing the results to a temp table and then displaying the categories by metric_report value

But i wanted to check if there is an option to get this in a static view/query itself.

updated db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43c39a4f88cd410f91e94f721ee7e75e

**Scripts**

```
create table metric_threshold
                  (  metric_id varchar(10)
                  , threshold_category varchar(30)
                  , symbol varchar(50)
                  , values1 varchar(20)
                  )


insert into metric_threshold values('Met1','In SLA','>','80')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met1','Mature','>=','70')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met1','Satisfactory','>=','60')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met1','Needs Improvement','<','60')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met2','In SLA','=','Y')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met2','Out of SLA','=','N')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met3','Mature','=','0')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met3','Needs Improvement','=','1')
insert into metric_threshold values('Met4','In SLA','>','80');
insert into metric_threshold values('Met4','Mature','>=','70');
insert into metric_threshold values('Met4','Satisfactory','<','60');
insert into metric_threshold values('Met4','Needs Improvement','<','50');

create table metric_report
              (  metric_id varchar(10)
              , reporting_date date
              , report_values varchar(20)
              )           


insert into metric_report values('Met1','2020-01-01','72.15')
insert into metric_report values('Met2','2020-01-01','Y')
insert into metric_report values('Met3','2020-01-01','0')
insert into metric_report values('Met1','2020-02-01','80')
insert into metric_report values('Met2','2020-02-01','Y')
insert into metric_report values('Met3','2020-02-01','1')
insert into metric_report values('Met1','2020-03-01','60')
insert into metric_report values('Met2','2020-03-01','Y')
insert into metric_report values('Met3','2020-03-01','1')
insert into metric_report values('Met4','2020-03-01','50');
```

Comment: Seemingly only Met1 seem volatile enough to require the mentioned handling... Met2 as well as Met3 look like regular yes/no flags - wouldn't it be easier to leave these alone and focus on Met1? This would give the possibility to handle the value as numeric only without the need to handly Y and N and so on...

Comment: The original table has got plenty of Met1 kid of metrics. Actually its a table that holds the metrics from multiple business teams, we are trying to build a common table or view so that the reporting layer can make use of one place to get all of "threshold_ranges". the ranges of threshold is defined in an user web-page where they can enter the values and define the rules

Comment: I totally agree, that Met1 needs a certain handling... but putting a y/n or a 1/0 "switch" into this kind of table mighr be a bit "oversized"... that is if there will never be other values than "y/n" and "1/0" for this kind of flag... however, should be doable as well :D I'll give it a try as soon as fiddle works again for me

Comment: If you have the flexibility to change the `metric_threshold` threshold this could provide a solution: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c53e3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach - might not be the prettiest but seems to work without changing your current table structure. The idea is - as mentioned in my comment - to evaluate "real" threasholds basing on the vlaues given vor Met1 and to handle all other metrics as "simple" flags. This can be adjusted as required:

```
WITH cteFlagsOnly AS(
SELECT metric_id, COUNT(DISTINCT symbol) cnt
  FROM metric_threshold
  WHERE symbol != N'='
  GROUP BY metric_id
),
cteNoRange AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT metric_id
    FROM metric_threshold
    WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(19,4), values1) IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT t.metric_id
    FROM metric_threshold t
    LEFT JOIN cteFlagsOnly f ON f.metric_id = t.metric_id
    WHERE f.metric_id IS NULL
),
cte AS(
SELECT t.*
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.metric_id ORDER BY values1 , CASE
                                                                             WHEN symbol = N'>' THEN 1
                                                                             WHEN symbol = N'>=' THEN 2
                                                                             WHEN symbol = N'=' THEN 3
                                                                             WHEN symbol = N'<=' THEN 4
                                                                             WHEN symbol = N'<' THEN 5
                                                                             ELSE 99
                                                                           END DESC) AS rn
  FROM metric_threshold t
  LEFT JOIN cteNoRange cn ON cn.metric_id = t.metric_id
  WHERE cn.metric_id IS NULL
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT *
      ,CAST(LAG(values1) OVER (PARTITION BY metric_id ORDER BY rn) AS DECIMAL(19,4)) AS valuesLag
      ,LAG(symbol) OVER (PARTITION BY metric_id ORDER BY rn) AS symbolLag
      ,CAST(LEAD(values1) OVER (PARTITION BY metric_id ORDER BY rn) AS DECIMAL(19,4)) AS valuesLead
      ,LEAD(symbol) OVER (PARTITION BY metric_id ORDER BY rn) AS symbolLead
  FROM cte c
),
cteThrashholds AS(
SELECT *
      ,CASE
         WHEN symbol IN (N'<', N'<=') THEN 0.0
         WHEN symbol = N'>' THEN CAST(values1 AS decimal(19,4)) + 0.000000001
         WHEN symbol = N'>=' THEN CAST(values1 AS decimal(19,4))
         ELSE NULL
       END AS ValFrom
      ,CASE
         WHEN symbol = N'<' THEN CAST(values1 AS decimal(19,4)) - 0.000000001
         WHEN symbol = N'<=' THEN CAST(values1 AS decimal(19,4))
         WHEN symbolLead = N'>=' THEN ISNULL(valuesLead - 0.000000001, 9999999.99)
         WHEN symbolLead = N'>' THEN ISNULL(valuesLead, 9999999.99)
         ELSE ISNULL(valuesLead, 9999999.99)
       END AS ValTo
  FROM cte2
)
SELECT mr.*, ct.threshold_category
  FROM metric_report mr
  LEFT JOIN cteNoRange cn ON cn.metric_id = mr.metric_id
  LEFT JOIN cteThrashholds ct ON ct.metric_id = mr.metric_id AND mr.report_values BETWEEN ct.ValFrom AND ct.ValTo
  WHERE cn.metric_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT mr.*, ct.threshold_category
  FROM metric_report mr
  INNER JOIN cteNoRange cn ON cn.metric_id = mr.metric_id
  LEFT JOIN metric_threshold ct ON ct.metric_id = mr.metric_id AND mr.report_values = ct.values1
ORDER BY mr.metric_ID
```

Comment: Thanks i will test this out

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph so, did this help solving the problem?

Comment: thanks it helps, however i am unable to hard code the <> 'Met1' since i wouldnt know before hand which ones are range bound with percentages.  Another case to consider is for Met4 scenario which i have updated the dbfiddle link and the question.The query gives me "Needs Improvment" when i am expecting "Satisfactory"

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph hello. I modified my answer to a less hardcoded version... this one excludes all non-numeric metrics and metrics which feature only the Symbol "=" (these are interepreted as flags / non-range metrics). All other metrics are considered as range metrics... please check - metric4 is now evaluated as "Satisfactory".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Kindly review sql script..

```
SELECT metric_id, 
       reporting_date, 
       report_values, 
       range 
FROM   (SELECT mth.metric_id, 
               rpt.reporting_date, 
               rpt.report_values, 
               mth.threshold_category AS Range, 
               CASE mth.symbol 
                 WHEN '>' THEN 
                   CASE 
                     WHEN Isnumeric(rpt.report_values) <> 0 THEN 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN rpt.report_values > mth.values1 THEN 
                         rpt.report_values + '>=' + mth.values1 
                         ELSE 'N' 
                       END 
                     ELSE 'N' 
                   END 
                 WHEN '>=' THEN 
                   CASE 
                     WHEN Isnumeric(rpt.report_values) <> 0 THEN 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN rpt.report_values >= mth.values1 THEN 
                         rpt.report_values + '>=' + mth.values1 
                         ELSE 'N' 
                       END 
                     ELSE 'N' 
                   END 
                 WHEN '<' THEN 
                   CASE 
                     WHEN Isnumeric(rpt.report_values) <> 0 THEN 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN rpt.report_values < mth.values1 THEN 
                         rpt.report_values + '>=' + mth.values1 
                         ELSE 'N' 
                       END 
                     ELSE 'N' 
                   END 
                 WHEN '=' THEN 
                   CASE 
                     WHEN Isnumeric(rpt.report_values) <> 0 THEN 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN rpt.report_values = mth.values1 THEN 
                         rpt.report_values + '>=' + mth.values1 
                         ELSE 'N' 
                       END 
                     ELSE 'N' 
                   END  
               END  AS Valid 
        FROM   metric_threshold mth, 
               metric_report rpt) AS x 
WHERE  x.valid <> 'N'
```

Comment: Thanks, its nearly close to what i want. I am looking for one range against each metric. It should match the expected output